# Sitecore Image imagescaling/resizing not working on CD enviornment

Tags: media-library, content-management, content-delivery

Recently our client asked us to use progressive image loading for our site.

So we decided to use sitecore's image scaling/resizing to get low resolution image using sitecore image-scaling parameters, e.g.

`localhost/~/media/homepage-images/x2-optimised/xyz.jpg?w=20&h=20&hash=98947F3FD40937B21D80262E6FEB7D72AF20821C`

It was working fine on testing, uat, Production CM but its not working on CD environment.

I have checked all the configs nothing unusual is there(we are also using Django for image compression also tried removing this still  not working), also i have tried disabling Media Protection its still not working.

Sitecore doesn't give any error it just returns the actual image not the scaled one.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update** : I Checked and it seems issue of cache or may be image generation
as cache key is showing

`?as=False&bc=0&h=0&iar=False&mh=0&mw=0&sc=0&thn=False&w=0`

in CD Environment

and in CM its shows

`?as=False&bc=0&h=20&iar=False&mh=0&mw=0&sc=0&thn=False&w=20`

I am not sure why this is happening, someone can help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What are the urls of images?

Comment: Hi @MarekMusielak i have edited the question, i mistakenly added HTTP:// so it got hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for, who may come searching the same issue in future.

My issue was not not related to sitecore actually the issue was one of the rewrite rules,

The rewrite rule was to remove querystring so before the resize processor begins the query was remove by rewrite rule so sitecore was giving the default query string (?as=False&bc=0&h=0&iar=False&mh=0&mw=0&sc=0&thn=False&w=0) in cache, so it was looking like cache was generated wrong but it wasn't the case.

So i removed the rule and it worked like the charm.